# What are the open source symbolic execution tools for windows binaries

Tags: windows, binary-analysis

I want to test some approach in symbolic execution in windows binaries and doesn't want to write a new one from scratch and also this tool must be reliable at research levels.

I found S2E and BitBlaze earlier but not any documentation for testing windows binaries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[Metasm](https://github.com/jjyg/metasm/)** and **[Miasm](https://github.com/cea-sec/miasm)** can perform symbolic execution on Windows binaries. *Metasm* is written in pure ruby with no dependencies. *Miasm* is written in python. You can find some usages of the above frameworks in the book *[Practical Reverse Engineering](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1502489309)*. Besides you can always Google for more.

[Here](http://blog.quarkslab.com/deobfuscation-recovering-an-ollvm-protected-program.html) is an hands-on example of using miasm for symbolic execution.

Comment: Thank you for your respond but is there any C or C++ based tool? I saw something about windows device driver analysis with S2E but not all binaries. besides It seems S2E based on Linux. I prefer a MS Windows based tool. by the way thank you I will look at these.